# Calculate the limit?

Tags: limits

[image]

The answer sheet says:

[image]

I understand all of this apaprt from the last bit where it says [image]

I don't understand how/why they have put logs and exponentials in there.

Comment: $x^2$ grows slower than $e^{kx}$ in the limit as $x \to \infty$ whenever $k > 0$, so $x^2(3/4)^x$ goes to $0$.

Comment: The issue is what happens to $x^2(3/4)^x$ as x gets large, since the $x^2$ gets large but the $(3/4)^x$ part approaches $0$.  In fact the exponential overwhelms the $x^2$ so the whole thing approaches $0$.  Many people are aware that $x^2/e^x$ approaches 0, because the denominator is exponential.  The exponential function increases faster than any power of $x$.  Same for e^(kx) for any $k>0$ so he/she used that as justification

Answer (score 0):

Since $exp$ and $log$ are reciprocals, then
\begin{equation*}
a^{b}=e^{\ln (a^{b})}=e^{b\ln a}.
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
\left( \frac{3}{4}\right) ^{x}=e^{x\ln \left( \frac{3}{4}\right) }=\frac{1}{%
e^{-x\ln \left( \frac{3}{4}\right) }}=\frac{1}{e^{x\ln \left( \frac{4}{3}%
\right) }}.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, $\ln \left( \frac{4}{3}\right) >0$ since $\ln x>0$ for
all $x>1,$ and $\frac{4}{3}>1.$

Answer (score 0):

The basic result needed
is that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x^na^x}{b^x}
= 0
$
for any
$n > 0$
and
$0 < a < b$.

Essentially,
an exponential function
of the form
$c^x$ where
$c > 1$
eventually grows faster
(for large enough $x$)
than any fixed power of $x$,
$x^n$,
no matter how large $n$ is
and how close to $1$
$c$ is.